# How to create a layout that's split diagonally and the two halves are clickable?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a layout that's split the screen diagonally into two parts with different colors as their background.Something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/

Comment: Do you want just to draw it like this or actually create new GroupView with right and left sub views with ability to add children views inside?

Comment: @sromku I want to create a groupview with right and left subviews with ability to add children views inside.

Comment: Extend LinearLayout in your own custom view group. http://www.jayway.com/2012/06/25/creating-custom-android-views-part-1-extending-standard-views-and-adding-new-xml-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows:

- Create a `FrameLayout` (lets say 50x50 pixels).
- Create two `ImageView`s (inside the `FrameLayout` and set them to `match_parent`) and as source give them the two triangles.
- Create an `onTouchListener` for the `FrameLayout`.

Now comes the tricky part:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me){ 
  float time  = System.getCurrentTimeInMilles();

  if(me.action == MotionEvent.DOWN)
    lastTimePress = time;   /// global var

  if(me.action == MotionEvent.UP && lastTimePress - time < 200){
    if(calcPlace(me.getX()) < me.getY())
      /// go to onClick for the right triangle
    else
      /// go to onClick for the left triangle
  }
}

public int calcPlace(int x){
  return 50 -x; 
}
```

You don't have to set `onClickListener` for the two triangles (`ImageView`s), just have a method that handles the clicks.

Some fields might be wrong, sorry about it :) I hope you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to create a View as the background, then put another one above it with a 45 degree angle. Put both inside a FrameLayout to clip it to a rect again. You may assign a onClick handler to each of them.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the background by xml. Make the `abc` image of the same background in a different size:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/abc"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```