# create custom imageview - listview

Tags: android, android-imageview

I would like to create below row for a `ListView` that each row has two **Imageviews** and the user can touch each of them (To open `Activity`).

[image]

How can I do ? I must create a custom `ImageView` ?

Comment: create this type of two placeholder and create row for it

Comment: I have two rectangular images !

Comment: yes but slice image of that shape and load using picasso

Comment: I have two images like this : smsbaz.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Corn.jpg , I get these images from a webservice !

Comment: using picasso you can load any image

Comment: my problem is not loading images !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83595/discussion-between-anand-savjani-and-s-m-emamian).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Fashizel at [How to create a layout that's split diagonally and the two halves are clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991986/how-to-create-a-layout-thats-split-diagonally-and-the-two-halves-are-clickable)

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:src="@drawable/image01"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:src="@drawable/image02"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Context mContext = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
    if (frameLayout != null) {
        frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    if(calcPlace(event.getX()) < calcPlace(event.getY())){
                        /// go to onClick for the right triangle
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"onClick for the right triangle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        /// go to onClick for the left triangle
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"onClick for the left triangle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}

private float calcPlace(float x){
    return 100 - x;
}   

...
}
```

02 image files: 02 triangles

[image]

[image]

[image]

Just a demo for the image views, you can use for your views

Hope this help!

Comment: I have two rectangular images ! I think in your example I must create two custom images !

Comment: The images of course are rectangular. Just need to use Photo Editors (like Photoshop) to make it half transparent.

Comment: your answer is true, but I have two images like this : http://smsbaz.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Corn.jpg , I get these images from a webservice !

Answer (score 0):

Might be this will help you in some case

```
Bitmap setBitmapInTriangleShape(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2,
        Bitmap bitmap3) {
    /*
     * int[] values= new int[2]; mImageView.getLocationOnScreen(values);
     */
    double screenHeightAspect = 2.5;
    Bitmap drawnBitmap = null;

    bitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap1, screenWidth,
            (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect), true);
    bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, screenWidth,
            (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect), true);
    bitmap3 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap3, screenWidth,
            (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect), true);

    try {
        drawnBitmap = Bitmap
                .createBitmap(screenWidth,
                        (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect),
                        Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(drawnBitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(
                R.color.gray_divider_reg_edit_grid_1));
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        Path path = new Path();
        BitmapShader bms = new BitmapShader(bitmap1, TileMode.CLAMP,
                TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setShader(bms);
        // bms.setLocalMatrix(matrix);

        // -----------------=for photo 1-----------------------------
        path.reset();
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

        path.lineTo(0, 0);
        path.lineTo((int) (screenWidth * 0.80), 0);
        // path.lineTo(0, 15);
        path.lineTo(0, (int) (screenHeight * 0.8706 / screenHeightAspect));
        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        Matrix mt = new Matrix();

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, new Matrix(), null);
        // -------------------for photo 3-----------------------------
        BitmapShader bmsUo = new BitmapShader(bitmap3, TileMode.CLAMP,
                TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setShader(bmsUo);
        // bms.setLocalMatrix(matrix);

        path.reset();
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        path.moveTo((int) (screenWidth * 0.80), 0);
        path.lineTo((int) (screenWidth * 0.80), 0);
        path.lineTo(screenWidth, 0);
        path.lineTo(screenWidth, (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect));
        // path.lineTo(800,800);
        path.lineTo((int) (screenWidth * 0.88),
                (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect));

        path.lineTo((int) (screenWidth * 0.50),
                (int) (screenHeight * 0.32 / screenHeightAspect));

        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        // ---------------------for photo 2-------------------------
        BitmapShader bmsUop = new BitmapShader(bitmap2, TileMode.CLAMP,
                TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setShader(bmsUop);
        // bmsUop.setLocalMatrix(matrix);
        path.reset();
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        path.moveTo((int) (screenWidth * 0.50),
                (int) (screenHeight * 0.32 / screenHeightAspect));
        path.lineTo((int) (screenWidth * 0.50),
                (int) (screenHeight * 0.32 / screenHeightAspect));
        path.lineTo((int) (screenWidth * 0.88),
                (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect));
        path.lineTo(0, (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect));
        path.lineTo(0, (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect * 0.8706));

        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return drawnBitmap;

}
```

for more information you can visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778690/triangle-shaped-imageview-with-drag-scroll-zoom-ontouch-android)