# Develop diagonal layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I would like to develop a layout which is diagonally divided in to two phases with option1 & option2.
I want both this diagonal layers to be touch sensible so that when user touch on it, its event get executed.
How can I develop such a layout?

I am attaching my Layouts rough design

[image]

```
<item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="40"
            android:toDegrees="120"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="0%">
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:width="2dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
```

This code gives me very small triangle and I am not able to increase its height & width.
Please help

Comment: [take a look](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266384/is-it-ok-to-downvote-questions-asking-about-how-to-achieve-something-without-ha)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991986/how-to-create-a-layout-thats-split-diagonally-and-the-two-halves-are-clickable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517589/making-a-triangle-shape-using-xml-definitions..this will give you an idea

Answer (score 1):

I will give some suggestion.

Take the relative layout as the base. Take a drawable with a triangle shape load into image view and place it on top of the layout you developed. Have a click listener for image view for an action and one for layout for another.